# Flutter Horizontal List View Dot Indicator

Tags: list, flutter, dart, view

I have multiple images each with their own redirect link. Currently this works fine at displaying using a list view build to display the images inside a gesture detector.

However, I’d like to add a dot indicator to show which image is being viewed. How can I get the index of the image being displayed? Or increase / decrease a counter when swiping left or right.

I’ve looked into carousels but they don’t seem to allow each image to redirect to somewhere else.

Comment: Can you share the code demonstrating what did you try so far so we can easily help you ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand you clear. with package https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider
swipe image to left or right can get current page from onPageChanged event 
and use InkWell wrap image, you can navigate to other page. In my demo just print click message

code snippet

```
final List child = map<Widget>(
  imgList,
  (index, i) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
        child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
          InkWell(
              onTap: () { print("you click  ${index} "); },
              child: Image.network(i, fit: BoxFit.cover, width: 1000.0)),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0.0,
            left: 0.0,
            right: 0.0,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [Color.fromARGB(200, 0, 0, 0), Color.fromARGB(0, 0, 0, 0)],
                  begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  end: Alignment.topCenter,
                ),
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
              child: Text(
                'No. $index image',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  },
).toList();

...

class _CarouselWithIndicatorState extends State<CarouselWithIndicator> {
  int _current = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      CarouselSlider(
        items: child,
        autoPlay: false,
        enlargeCenterPage: true,
        aspectRatio: 2.0,
        onPageChanged: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _current = index;
            print("${_current}");
          });
        },
      ),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: map<Widget>(
          imgList,
          (index, url) {
            return Container(
              width: 8.0,
              height: 8.0,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 2.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  color: _current == index
                      ? Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.9)
                      : Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.4)),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    ]);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: what is map<Widget> because it is giving me an error

Comment: @VipulChauhan it' from official example https://github.com/serenader2014/flutter_carousel_slider/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart , could you post your code to another question? thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I found my answer with carousel slider and Dots indicator

Comment: @VipulChauhan What was the solution? Also getting `The method 'map' isn't defined for the class`

Comment: the map is giving an error please can you show how did you wrote ?

Answer (score 13):

As per example pointed to by [@chunhunghan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2179571/chunhunghan) above in the comments, you need to replace `map<Widget> ( (image, url) {..}`
with
`imgList.map((image) {int index = imgList.indexOf(image); ..}`

I was able to get it to work with the above change. Revised code snippet for the build method:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      CarouselSlider(
        items: child,
        autoPlay: false,
        enlargeCenterPage: true,
        aspectRatio: 2.0,
        onPageChanged: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _current = index;
            print("${_current}");
          });
        },
      ),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: imgList.map((image) {       //these two lines 
            int index=imgList.indexOf(image); //are changed
            return Container(
              width: 8.0,
              height: 8.0,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 2.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  color: _current == index
                      ? Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.9)
                      : Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.4)),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    ]);
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

The solution I found, besides change map to use imgList, was to put .toList() at the imgList.map function return as follows:

```
@override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      CarouselSlider(
        items: child,
        autoPlay: false,
        enlargeCenterPage: true,
        aspectRatio: 2.0,
        onPageChanged: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _current = index;
            print("${_current}");
          });
        },
      ),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: imgList.map((image) {     
            int index=imgList.indexOf(image);
            return Container(
              width: 8.0,
              height: 8.0,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 2.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  color: _current == index
                      ? Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.9)
                      : Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.4)
              ),
            );
          },
        ).toList(), // this was the part the I had to add
      ),
    ]);
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

**Vertical Indicators On Slider or Flutter Carousel**

```
class VerticalSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _VerticalSliderState createState() => _VerticalSliderState();
}
class _VerticalSliderState extends State<VerticalSlider> {

  List imageSliders=[
//add your items here
];
  int _current = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Vertical sliding carousel ')),
      body: Stack(

        children: [
          Container(
            child: CarouselSlider(
              options: CarouselOptions(
                viewportFraction: .6,
                aspectRatio: 1.2,
                enlargeCenterPage: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                autoPlay: true,
                 onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                setState(() {
                  _current = index;
                });
              }
              ),
              items: imageSliders,
            )
          ),
           Positioned(
            top: 50,
            right: 10,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: imgList.map((url) {
                int index = imgList.indexOf(url);
                return Container(
                  width: 8.0,
                  height: 8.0,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0, horizontal: 2.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    color: _current == index
                      ? Colors.white60
                      : Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.4),
                  ),
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And you may add custom indicators too.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use `CarouselSlider` with the `AnimatedSmoothIndicator` widget

```
 int _current = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Column(children: [
      CarouselSlider(
        options: CarouselOptions(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
            onPageChanged: (i, r) {
              setState(() {
                _current = i;
              });
            }),
        items: imageList.map((e) => Container(
                  child: Image.network(e, fit: BoxFit.cover),
                ))
            .toList(),
      ),
      Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 2.0),
        child: AnimatedSmoothIndicator(
          activeIndex: _current,
          count: imageList.length,
          effect: ExpandingDotsEffect(
              activeDotColor: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.9),
              dotWidth: 8,
              dotHeight: 8),
        ),
      )
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

add auto slider code for flutter like this....

[output screen shorts is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTBnq.png)

```
class _ProductDetailsState extends State<ProductDetails> {

  List imageSliders = [
    'assets/images/man_1.png',
    'assets/images/man_2.png',
    'assets/images/man_3.png',
    'assets/images/woman_1.png',
    'assets/images/woman_2.png',
    'assets/images/woman_3.png',
    'assets/images/woman_4.png',
    'assets/images/woman_5.png',
    'assets/images/woman_6.png',
    'assets/images/woman_7.png',
  ];


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      systemNavigationBarColor: Color(0xFF000000),
      systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
      systemNavigationBarDividerColor: null,
      statusBarColor: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
      statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
      statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark,
    ));

    return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          appBar: AppBar(
            elevation: 0,
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            leading: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 20,
                top: 10,
              ),
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.keyboard_backspace_sharp,
                  size: 35,
                  color: Colors.grey[600],
                ),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              ),
            ),
            actions: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 0,
                  top: 10,
                ),
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.search_outlined,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    size: 30,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 0,
                  top: 10,
                  right: 20,
                ),
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: Stack(
                    children: [
                      if (_newNotification)
                        Positioned(
                          right: 1,
                          top: 1,
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.red),
                            width: 20.0 / 2.5,
                            height: 20.0 / 2.5,
                          ),
                        ),
                      Icon(
                        Icons.notifications_none_outlined,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        size: 30,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                  child: CarouselSlider(
                    options: CarouselOptions(
                      height: 200,
                        viewportFraction: .6,
                        aspectRatio: 1.2,
                        enlargeCenterPage: true,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        autoPlay: true,
                        onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                          setState(() {
                            activeIndex = index;
                          });
                        }
                    ),
                    items: [
                      for(var item in imageSliders ) Image.asset(item)
                    ],
                  )
              ),
              Positioned(
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: imageSliders.map((url) {
                    int index = imageSliders.indexOf(url);
                    return Container(
                      width: 8.0,
                      height: 8.0,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0, horizontal: 2.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        color: activeIndex == index
                            ? Colors.blue
                            : Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.4),
                      ),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                ),
              ),
    
            ],
          ),
        );
   }
}
```